# Overwrite an file which is currently open and it use in c#

Tags: c#, file, overwrite

I am using C# to create a GUI which has a logging feature. When I create the log file, I provide it a filename. But I have the following issue. For instance, if the file is already open in the background on my desktop and I want to name my filename as the same, I get the exception message as following:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\blah\blah\mytest.csv' because it is being used by another process.
```

I am using the following piece of code to check if the file exists and using the streamwriter to create the new file.

```
if (FileUtils.Exists(fileName))
            {
                if (!FileUtils.Delete(fileName))
                {
                    cout<< Error replacing log file, it might be used by another process"; 
                }             
            }

//Exception handling
     public static bool Delete(string myfiletowrite)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(myfiletowrite);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            } 
myfile= new StreamWriter(myfiletowrite, true); //exception occurs here when I try to write to myfiletowrite which is currently open
```

I am unsure on how to close this file which is open in the background so I could write to this file. I would appreciate it someone could help me with this.

Comment: You can't. You'll have to kill the background process that has the file opened.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  I created the file using the log feature from my C# tool. And then I want to create another log file but with the same name and that file is currently open. Is there ar way to handle this in code?

Comment: It would be pretty bad if the OS provided a mechanism to allow you to force overwrite a file that somebody else has open. Your best bet would be to try to open the file you want, and if it fails, try again with a different file name. Append a timestamp for instance.

Comment: @Analia Why do you want to have the same file open twice in the same program? That is not a good design.

Comment: @TypeIA When I created the log file name, I gave it the same name to see if my code can handle it. But it would break at the line with myfile. Thats why I want to handle it in the code like close the file and then create it.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you can work with a file that doesn't prevent others from opening the file.  For example, Notepad, when you open a file, opens it, reads all the text and then closes it.  Having a file open in Notepad doesn't get in the way of anyone else opening the file.  You can also open a file for read or for write, and set the sharing of the file when you open it.  But, if you have a file open in some app that's taken a lock, and you want to open the file for writing, you aren't going to succeed.

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you considered leveraging the FileSystemWatcher class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2)?  You could effectively wait for the file to become available.  You might find it's better if you check first before you overwrite any changes, but this gives you the option either way.

Comment: you cannot have 2 files with same name, either delete old one and create a new one or overwrite the content in exist file

Comment: @saif How do i overwrite the contents with streamwriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other application did not explicitely allow it (via Share mode), it is not possible to open the file for writing.

If the other application is under your control, you have some options (open the file with `FileShare.Write`, implement some communication protocol between the two applications, use a common service for accessing the file, ...).

Best option would be to choose a different file name.